# Aborting/canceling tasks that consist of a single unbreakable operation

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I'm making an app that copies remote network files over to local disk and the whole operation consists of `File.Copy(remotePath, localPath)` calls. Sometimes copy operations hang or run extra slowly but don't throw any exceptions yet, but I want to stop it, and there is no way to check for `IsCancellationRequested` from a cancellation token, like many posts here recommend for cases where the operations are divisible. What do I do in this case for canceling tasks?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortuantly .NET has no managed way to cancel a file copy operation, to my knowledge it can only be done via native calls.

The native call you would need to make is to [FileCopyEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363852(v=vs.85).aspx) it has a parameter and a callback function that allows for cancellation.

Here is how you would do it in .NET:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool CopyFileEx(string lpExistingFileName, string lpNewFileName,
    CopyProgressRoutine lpProgressRoutine, IntPtr lpData, ref bool pbCancel,
    CopyFileFlags dwCopyFlags);

private const int CopyCanceledErrorCode = 1235;

private static void Copy(string oldFile, string newFile, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var cancel = false;

    CopyProgressRoutine callback =
        (size, transferred, streamSize, bytesTransferred, number, reason, file, destinationFile, data) =>
        {
            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                return CopyProgressResult.PROGRESS_CANCEL;
            else
                return CopyProgressResult.PROGRESS_CONTINUE;
        };

    if (!CopyFileEx(oldFile, newFile, callback, IntPtr.Zero, ref cancel, CopyFileFlags.COPY_FILE_RESTARTABLE))
    {
        var error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        if (error == CopyCanceledErrorCode)
            throw new OperationCanceledException(cancellationToken);
                //Throws the more .NET friendly OperationCanceledException
        throw new Win32Exception(error);
    }
    //This prevents the callback delegate from getting GC'ed before the native call is done with it.
    GC.KeepAlive(callback);
}
```

---

One thing to note, my first attempt at this was

```
private static void Copy(string oldFile, string newFile, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    bool cancel = false;
    using (cancellationToken.Register(() => cancel = true))
    {
        if (!CopyFileEx(oldFile, newFile, null, IntPtr.Zero, ref cancel, CopyFileFlags.COPY_FILE_RESTARTABLE))
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }
        GC.KeepAlive(cancel);
    }
}
```

but that did not cause the the copy to cancel. I don't know if it was just because you can't change the bool from a delegate or if it was because CopyFileEx does not check as frequently to see if the bool changes. Using the callback method of canceling the copy is much more reliable.

---

APPENDEX:

Here is a copy of all of the enums and delegates so you don't need to hunt them down on Pinvoke.net like I did.

```
enum CopyProgressResult : uint
{
    PROGRESS_CONTINUE = 0,
    PROGRESS_CANCEL = 1,
    PROGRESS_STOP = 2,
    PROGRESS_QUIET = 3
}
enum CopyProgressCallbackReason : uint
{
    CALLBACK_CHUNK_FINISHED = 0x00000000,
    CALLBACK_STREAM_SWITCH = 0x00000001
}

[Flags]
enum CopyFileFlags : uint
{
    COPY_FILE_FAIL_IF_EXISTS = 0x00000001,
    COPY_FILE_RESTARTABLE = 0x00000002,
    COPY_FILE_OPEN_SOURCE_FOR_WRITE = 0x00000004,
    COPY_FILE_ALLOW_DECRYPTED_DESTINATION = 0x00000008,
    COPY_FILE_COPY_SYMLINK = 0x00000800 //NT 6.0+
}

delegate CopyProgressResult CopyProgressRoutine(
    long TotalFileSize,
    long TotalBytesTransferred,
    long StreamSize,
    long StreamBytesTransferred,
    uint dwStreamNumber,
    CopyProgressCallbackReason dwCallbackReason,
    IntPtr hSourceFile,
    IntPtr hDestinationFile,
    IntPtr lpData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Open both files a FileStream and copy it in chunks.
Use if u can the async methods.

The simple form is to read data to buffer and write the 
buffer out. The extened Version is to read in one buffer
and write from a second buffer at the same time.

after or before each read/write call, the Operation is 
cancelable.

If there is a Problem u will get at some Point a timeoutexception
depending on the ReadTimeout WriteTimeout property of the stream.

The Windows Default buffer size is 4096 Bytes.
Here are to Extension methods:

```
public static void WriteTo(this Stream source, Stream distiantion, int bufferSize = PNetIO.DefaultBufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int c;
        while ((c = source.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) > 0)
        {
            distiantion.Write(buffer, 0, c);
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }
    }

    public static async Task WriteToAsync(this Stream source, Stream distiantion, int bufferSize = PNetIO.DefaultBufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        if (!source.CanRead)
            return;

        var buffer = new Byte[bufferSize * 2];

        var c = await source.ReadAsync(buffer, bufferSize, bufferSize, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (c <= 0)
            return;

        var w = distiantion.WriteAsync(buffer, bufferSize, c, cancellationToken);
        while ((c = await source.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, bufferSize).ConfigureAwait(false)) > 0)
        {
            await w.ConfigureAwait(false);
            w = distiantion.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, c, cancellationToken);

            if ((c = await source.ReadAsync(buffer, bufferSize, bufferSize, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false)) <= 0)
                break;

            await w.ConfigureAwait(false);
            w = distiantion.WriteAsync(buffer, bufferSize, c, cancellationToken);
        }

        await w.ConfigureAwait(false);
        await distiantion.FlushAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

You can use it like this:

```
var cancel = new CancellationTokenSource();

        using (var source = File.OpenRead("source"))
        using (var dest = File.OpenWrite("dest"))
            await source.WriteToAsync(dest, cancellationToken: cancel.Token);
```